# Adding Slide show with JavaScript is messing up my divs

Tags: javascript

I am not too experienced with JavaScript.

I have created a website with 5 divs on the container. When I added the Slideshow with JavaScript all the images jump to the top and the image I use as header for the site becomes another image from the slideshow.

I tried assigning a class to the images on the slideshow, but I dont know how to incorporate this to the code on JavaScript so that it only focuses on those (instead of all the images on my page).

(THANKS A LOT IF ANYONE CAN HELP!!!  I am not being lazy, I just can not seem to find the answer!!!)

Here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url(layout/background.png);
}
img{
-webkit-transition-property:opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration:5s;
position:absolute;
width:320;
height:auto;
}
img.fade-out{opacity:0;}
img.fade-in{opacity:1;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<br>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="main-menu4.gif" width="984" height="290" ></li>
  </ul>
 </div>


<div id="main_image">
<h1>Events</h1>
<br>
<img class="slideshow" src="hotdog.jpeg" width="450" height="auto" >
<img src="girlonslide.jpeg" width="450" height="auto" class="slideshow">
<img src="games/extremefun.jpg" width="450" height="auto" class="slideshow">
<img src="games/climbing.jpeg" width="450" height="auto" class="slideshow">
<img src="games/cartgame.jpeg" width="450" height="auto" class="slideshow">
<img src="pizza.JPG" width="450" height="auto" class="slideshow">
<script>

var interval = 4 * 20; //Seconds between change

var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imageArray = [];
var imageCount = images.length;
var current = 0;

var randomize = function(){
  return (Math.round(Math.random() * 3 - 1.5));
}
for(var i = 0; i < imageCount; i++){
  images[i].className = 'fade-out';
  imageArray[i] = images [i];
}
imageArray.sort(randomize);

var fade = function() {

  imageArray[current++].className = 'fade-out';
  if(current == imageCount){
      current = 0;
      imageArray.sort(randomize);
  }
  imageArray[current].className = 'fade-in';

  setTimeout(fade, interval * 100);
 };
 fade();
 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I really dont know what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be targeting all the image tags in your page. You need to limit that to only the images in your `div#main_image`.

**To do that replace**

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

**with**

```
var images = document.getElementById("main_image").getElementsByTagName("img");
```